# Email alert on AWS for webservice health

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch

I have deployed a webservice on AWS EC2 instances. 
I have also implemented a rest call `/getStatus`which returns status of modules in my service in JSON format like Connection status of DB, ActiveMQ cache status etc.

I want a way to creat automatic email trigger which will send mail when there is any issue found in response of `/getStatus` rest call.

I am looking if its possible using cloudwatch but any other sugestions are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a cloudwatch event that runs on a schedule you decide (i.e. every 5 minutes).

The event would call a lambda function, which would make the /getStatus call and decide if an email needs to be sent - if it does, I would further suggest AWS SES to send a custom formatted email with the appropriate alerts to the person(s) that are supposed to get them.

Using the above tools would be 'serverless', and cost very little to nothing and have the benefit of not running on a instance you have to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to make the endpoint return an HTTP status code indicating that something isn't correct (like a 500) and then set up a [Route53 Health Check with e-mail notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/health-checks-creating.html#health-checks-creating-values-alarm) (using SNS).

Answer (score 2):

The basic procedure for configuring email alerts is pretty straightforward. Use this flowchart to get started.

[image: Route 53 alert]

If you want detailed instructions, this [guide](https://axibase.com/use-cases/integrations/aws/route53-health-checks/) covers how to set up AWS email alerts upon resource status change and includes a few additional steps to refine the reports to be a bit more user-friendly and sent directly to a third-party messenger service.

The workflow will look like this:

1. Create **Route53 Health Check**;
2. Route53 initializes Health Checker Nodes in various regions;
3. Health Checkers ping the specified URL;

4a. Status is **OK** if TCP connection is established within 10 seconds and HTTP status code 2xx or 3xx is retrieved within 2 seconds;

**OR**

4b. Status is **FAILURE** otherwise: TCP connection fails, TCP connection times out, HTTP status code is 4xx, 5xx or page is too slow (yes, slow 200 response can cause failure);

5. Health Checker nodes will retry the endpoint as configured;
6. Cloud watch alarm is triggered on Health Check status change;
7. Alarm is delivered to AWS SNS topic
8. AWS SNS notifies topic subscribers
9. Advanced configuration may be applied to enhance notification contents and delivery method per above guide.

I work for the team that develops Axibase Time Series Database (atsd).